# MPI I/O, matching processes to files

Tags: io, mpi

I have a number of files, say 100 and a number of processors, say 1000.  Each proc needs to read parts of some subset of files. For instance, proc 3 needs `file04.dat`, `file05.dat`, and `file09.dat`, while proc 4 needs `file04.dat`, `file07.dat`, and `file08.dat.`, etc.  Which files are needed by which procs are not known at compile time and cannot be determined from any algorithm, but are easily determined during runtime from an existing metadata file.

I am trying to determine the best way to do this, using MPI I/O. It occurs to me that I could just have all the procs cycle through the files they need, calling `MPI_File_open` with `MPI_COMM_SELF` as the communicator argument. However, I'm a beginner with MPI I/O, and I suspect this would create some problems with large numbers of procs or files.  Is this the case?

I have also thought that perhaps the thing to do would be to establish a separate communicator for each file, and each processor that needs a particular file would be a member of the file's associated communicator.  But here, first, would that be a good idea?  And second, I'm not an expert on communicators either and I can't figure out how to set up the communicators in this manner.  Any ideas?

And if anyone has a completely different idea that would work better, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Try it, set up a test and see what happens.

Comment: OK, but I would also like to set up and test having one communicator per file, and I can't figure out how to set it up, as I indicated.  So I would like some help with that if it's available.  Can't test what I can't set up.